# Convert nested array to JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-3

This code:

```
@countries.map { |l| [l.country_name, l.latitude, l.longitude, l.capital] }
```

returns

```
[["country_name_1", latitude, longitude, capital],["country_name_2", latitude, longitude, capital],...]
```

But I need to convert to JSON; something like this:

```
{
   "country_name_1" : [latitude, longitude, "capital"],
   "country_name_2" : [latitude, longitude, "capital"],
   .
   .
   .
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
Hash[@countries.map { |l| [l.country_name, [l.latitude, l.longitude, l.capital]] }]
```

Rails also provides [`index_by`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Enumerable.html#method-i-index_by):

```
@countries.index_by(&:country_name)
# => {
#      "country_name_1" => #<Country latitude:..., longitude:...>,
#      "country_name_2" => #<Country latitude:..., longitude:...>,
#    }
```

Objects might be more convenient than hashes.

#### Regarding JSON

Rails has built-in support for JSON: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-json

You can also call [`to_json`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-to_json) manually:

```
hash = Hash[@countries.map { |l| [l.country_name, [l.latitude, l.longitude, l.capital]] }]
hash.to_json
```

Or use the [JSON Builder](https://github.com/dewski/json_builder) gem.

Comment: This returns, country_name = [...] but I need country_name : [...]

Comment: Do you need a Ruby hash or something like JSON?